# Homomorphic RSA

Tags: rsa, homomorphic-encryption

Anyone know how can I perform this ?
$$E(x_1)*E(x_2)=E(x_1*x_2)$$
I have already produced the keys and I can encrypt and decrypt using RSA. My goal is to multiply 2 encrypted integers in order to decrypt them and show how homomorphism works.
I cant find the product of the two encrypted integers because i am not sure how to multiple( byte by byte or whole integers)? If any

Answer (score 3):

With textbook RSA encryption defined as $E(x)=(x^e\bmod N)$ and decryption $D(y)=(y^d\bmod N)$, restricting to $0\le x_1<\sqrt N$ and $0\le x_2<\sqrt N$, we have$$E(x_1*x_2)=((E(x_1)*E(x_2))\bmod N)$$which let one compute $E(x_1*x_2)$ from $E(x_1)$ and $E(x_2)$; and $D(E(x_1*x_2))=x_1*x_2$, thus the enciphered product can be deciphered.

Note: in the above, all quantities are integers, $*$ is is integer multiplication, and $\bmod$ is modular reduction (similar to the `%` operator of C and Java), applied to large integers. $x^k\bmod N$ is equivalent to $1$ multiplied $k$ times by $x$ then reduced modulo $N$, but is to be computed with some efficient [modular exponentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation) method. The code implementing this multiplication, modular reduction, and modular exponentiation must be consistent with whatever representation of integers as bytes is used; no *"byte by byte"* multiplication has such consistency.

Problems are: textbook RSA encryption is not safe by modern cryptographic standards (in particular, any guess of $x$ can be checked by one knowing $x^e\bmod N$); and variants of textbook RSA safe against this are not homomorphisms (they are not even functions).

Comment: Thanks for your fast respond! I do not care about security. I want to perform an application thats multiplies two encrypted integers and i want to prove the mathematical equation. I cant find the product of the encrypted integers because i am not sure if i must multiply byte by byte or the whole number (binary).

Comment: @Teo Adam: that you _"do not care about security"_ is a strong indication that your question is off-topic.

Comment: If i cared about security i wouldnt use Rsa. This is a research for my school. I will create the code and then i will attack it.